# heroku installs sqlite3 but not being used in app

Tags: sqlite, heroku

When deploying my flask app to heroku it always seems to install sqlite3:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Using cached install of python-3.8.10
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 101.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
```

Sqlite is not used in my app, so I was wondering if anyone knows why it is being used?

Here is my package file:

```
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
click==8.0.1
cycler==0.10.0
Flask==2.0.1
Flask-WTF==0.15.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
kiwisolver==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
matplotlib==3.4.2
numpy==1.20.3
pandas==1.2.4
Pillow==8.2.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-dotenv==0.17.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.5
Werkzeug==2.0.1
WTForms==2.3.3
```

Thanks
Martyn

Comment: How many branches you have in this project? This is a possibility that you are deploying another branch to Heroku which has `sqllite3` as a dependency. Like some development stage branch

Comment: Only one branch - master